# Change screen libgdx, not working

Tags: java, libgdx, screen

just wondered how you chang screens in libgdx (screen implements screen). I tried and set it up to change screen on screentap on phone , or when space is pressed in pc, but the game doesn't respond in any way at all. Any ideas?

Game class:

```
package com.kapres.bounce;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

/**
* Created by KnutAndre on 12/20/2016.
*/

public class BounceGame extends Game {
@Override
 public void create() {
    showMenuScreen();
 }

 public void showMenuScreen(){
    setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
 }

 public void showGameScreen(){
    setScreen(new GameScreen());
 }
}
```

Menu Screen:

```
package com.kapres.bounce;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

/**
* Created by KnutAndre on 12/26/2016.
*/

public class MenuScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {

BounceGame game;

ShapeRenderer renderer;
FitViewport menuViewport;

public MenuScreen(BounceGame game) {this.game = game;}

@Override
public void show() {
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    menuViewport = new FitViewport(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH,   Constants.WORLD_HEIGTH);
    renderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    menuViewport.apply(true);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.r, Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.g, Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.b, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(menuViewport.getCamera().combined);

    renderer.begin();
    renderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.circle(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH/2, Constants.WORLD_HEIGTH/2, Constants.START_BUTTON_RADIUS, 50);
    renderer.end();
}

@Override

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    menuViewport.update(width, height, true);
   // menuViewport.getCamera().position.set(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH/2, Constants.WORLD_HEIGTH/2);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    renderer.dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    renderer.dispose();
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    if (keyCode == Input.Keys.SPACE){
        game.showGameScreen();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
    game.showGameScreen();
    return true;
}
```

}

Game Screen:

```
package com.kapres.bounce;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;


/**
* Created by KnutAndre on 12/20/2016.
*/

public class GameScreen implements Screen{

ShapeRenderer renderer;
FitViewport gameViewport;
Ball ball;

@Override
public void show() {
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    gameViewport = new FitViewport(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGTH);
    ball = new Ball(gameViewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(ball);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    gameViewport.apply(true);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.r, Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.g, Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR.b, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameViewport.getCamera().combined);

    renderer.begin();
    ball.render(renderer, delta);
    renderer.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gameViewport.update(width, height, true);
    ball.init();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    renderer.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set the input processor

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(var);
```

You should call this method in the `MenuScreen` `show()` method. This way the engine will be aware of your input processor*.

The code will looks like this:

```
public class MenuScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {

    ...

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

* The `InputAdapter` is just a class that implements the `InputProcessor` interface.

There is also a class called `InputMultiplexer` in case you need more then one input processor at the same time.

**Docs:**

[InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)

[InputAdapter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputAdapter.html)

[InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call `super.render()` in your `render()` method of `BounceGame` class (it's not presented on your snippets), e.g:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE)) {
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
}
```

It renders the screen if it's not null (e.g. `setScreen(new MainScreen())` method was called before). The `render()` method from superclass `Game`:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```